# Which data structure is more efficient for A*?

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, binary-search-tree, a-star, min-heap

In A* search, which data structure would be more efficient ? Min-heap or Binary search tree.

Considering that below operations are to be handled frequently:
(a) extract min
(b) search a node
(c) update the node
(d) insert a node

Note: Search operation would be very frequent as we need to check the presence of each probable child node in the open-list of A*.

Comment: It might take a little longer, but you can always implement both and time them to see which one suits you better

Comment: What exactly do you need *search* for in the A* algorithm? If you refer to updating the score of a node, then you already have the node (from the tree that is being searched), and can make sure you have (and maintain) the connection with the related heap node. I don't see why you would really need to search a certain key in the heap.

Answer (score 1):

A min-heap is a much simpler data structure than a balanced binary search tree, and it's typically implemented in an array, which reduces memory used and improves cache locality.

For these reasons, a min-heap implementation will be much faster if you do it right.

It's often tricky to implement the decrease-key operation in an array-based min-heap, though.  The usual solution is *not* to implement decrease-key at all, but just to insert another record in the min-heap whenever the distance to a node is decreased.

This will not increase the time complexity of the algorithm, the min-heap will take O(|E|) space.  If your graph is very dense, then a node's weight may be decreased many times, and this memory consumption might be too much.  If that's so, then you should just clean up the min-heap -- remove invalid entries and re-heapify -- whenever more than half of the entries in the heap are invalid.  This will keep memory consumption down to O(|V|) without significantly affecting run time.

Comment: @aks, a), no, you just keep the current distance to each vertex in a separate array.  You put a node in the heap when the distance decreases, and then you can recognize the invalid heap nodes, because they have a distance that doesn't match.

Comment: @aks, b) no, it means removing invalid heap nodes, which you can recognize in constant time as mentioned in my previous comment.  The cleaning process should only require a single scan through the heap array, and then a re-heapify, both of which take O(|V|) time.  Note that there will be no valid closed nodes in the heap, so you don't need to look at the closed list.

Comment: Normally vertexes are densely numbered, so an array (that's a list in python) is better than a dictionary for storing vertex information.

Comment: You keep saying you have to do linear searches when linear searches are not required :)

Comment: A 2D numpy array is a good choice